# Web Request error "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password". Any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, permissions

I am trying to write a file to a network drive from my asp.Net application and i get this error - Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. Any ideas?

I am able to write to a local drive line C:/temp
But when I try to save the file to a network drive such as \Server\Folder, I get the error mentioned above.

Any ideas people?

Comment: Answer to my question was Impersonation. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Impersonation did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net is running under specific user name, and probably this user name did not have permissions to access this directory.

Comment: I did have all permissions set up properly. But anyways....solved it today.....Impersonation did the trick for me. THanks guys!!